# Safe bash configuration file

Tags: bash

I'd like to configure a bash script from a config file.

I'd like to have a *sort of* safe and robust solution.

- [robust]: do not try to be too smart (and buggy) with a regex.

So the most "common" solution, which sources the config file is not an option for me, because the config file below will do funny things:

```sh
touch your_computer_is_hacked
foo=bar
```

What is the best practice for config files?
So I can have all values in an associative array? I don't care the actual format (bash script, yaml, ini, xml, javascript), but it should be fully specified, so if I'd like to add a space / newline  or <kbd>ő</kbd> character to the foo variable, it should be specified how to do it.

Comment: What details should I add to be accepted?

Comment: It's also asking for a third-party tool, which is off-topic as well.

Comment: So is it off-topic to ask for a library for bash, which does x?

Comment: [What topics can we ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) `Questions asking us to ... find a ... software library ... are off-topic`. The common solution is just to `source` the file and trust the user. It also gives user control, for example `MAKEFLAGS="-j$(nproc)"` getting number of cores dynamically. For what you ask, write your own parser.

Comment: @KamilCuk but simply asking for best practice in bash is ok, right? :)

Comment: I find your question fully legitimate. And I suggest to read line by line the config file, from your script.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to write `source <(...)`, where `...` is a command that reads from standard input and writes out the desired mappings. That way, `...` can be a Perl script or Python script or whatnot, which is easier than doing this in pure Bash.

At the bottom of this answer is a simple example that satisfies your requirements. It creates a function called `source-assoc-array` that populates an associative array specified by the caller (which the caller needs to have predeclared) using information read from standard input (which, in typical cases, will be redirected from a file). The format to pass on standard input is as follows:

- One assignment per line. No blank lines, no comment lines, no assignments spanning multiple lines, no commands other than assignments.
- Each assignment takes the form `key=value`. No whitespace is allowed, except of course that `value` can contain whitespace.
- The key is one or more ASCII letters, digits, and underscores, not starting with a digit. (These are the rules for Bash variable-names.)
- The value is zero or more non-null bytes. ([Bash words can't contain null bytes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/174016/12378), so that's an unavoidable limitation.) Newlines are represented as `\n`; backslashes are represented as `\\`; all other bytes are represented as themselves.
- So, for example, the line `foo='bar\n\\\nbaz'` is translated to `arr[foo]=$'\'bar\n\\\nbaz\''`, if `arr` is the name of the associative array.
- The function aborts with an error-message if it encounters any line that doesn't meet the above rules.

You can easily make the format more user-friendly by supporting various features such as blank lines, comments, leading and trailing whitespace (including trailing carriage-returns, to support Windows line endings), whitespace around `=`, and other escape sequences besides `\n` and `\\`.

You might also want to think through your threat model a bit more. For example, is it a problem if the user puts weird characters in the file (carriage returns, right-to-left characters, control characters, etc.) that makes it hard for a system admin to understand exactly what the mappings will be? (The below function emits error-messages that don't include the problematic line — just the line number — for this reason.) Is possible for the user to trick your script into reading a massive file that causes Bash to run out of memory, or into reading a device file such as `/dev/random`? And of course, any configuration like this automatically means that the user's input is expected to affect the later behavior of your script; you need to make sure that no possible effect is one that you consider harmful.

---

Without further do, here's the function:

```
source-assoc-array() {
  if [[ "$1" = -- ]] ; then
    shift
  fi
  if [[ "$#" != 1 ]] ; then
    echo 'Usage: source-assoc-array ARRAY_NAME < FILE' >&2
    return 1
  fi
  if ! [[ "$(declare -p -- "$1" 2>&1)" == 'declare -A '* ]] ; then
    printf '[%s] is not an associative array.\n' "$1" >&2
    return 1
  fi
  source <(
    perl -w -e '
      my $array_name = $ARGV[0];
      while (<STDIN>) {
        unless (m/^([^=]*)=(.*)$/) {
          die "[source-assoc-array] Error on line $.: No equals sign.\n";
        }
        my ($key, $val) = ($1, $2);
        unless ($key =~ m/^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*$/) {
          die "[source-assoc-array] Error on line $.: Invalid key.\n";
        }
        if ($val =~ m/\0/) {
          die "[source-assoc-array] Error on line $.: Null byte.\n";
        }
        unless ($val =~ m/^(?:[^\\]|\\[\\n])*$/) {
          die "[source-assoc-array] Error on line $.: Unescaped backslash.\n";
        }
        $val =~ s/\x27/\\\x27/g; # escape single-quotes
        print "$array_name\[$key]=\$\x27$val\x27\n";
      }
    ' -- "$1" \
    || echo 'return 1'
  )
}
```